# Python: How do you make 2 values in two different functions equal?

Tags: python, dice, blackjack

So I'm trying to program a blackjack game in Python by using randomed dice and I was trying to compare the player function to the dealer function, but I don't know how to make one function compared to the other? If you could explain how I could make one local variable in a function equal to another local variable in a different function, that would be much appreciated. The code is for if you just want to see what I'm trying to do, it isn't completed.

## A program to play Blackjack Dice.

```
import random
def roll_die():
return random.randint(1, 11)

def player():
    ''' 
    Implements what happens on player's turn. 
    Returns total and blackjack, which represents
    the player's total score and whether the
    player hit Blackjack, respectively.
    '''
    blackjack = False
    total = 0

    print('************ YOUR TURN ************')
    die1 = random.randint(1,11)
    die2 = random.randint(1,11)
    if die1 == 11 and die2 == 11:
        die1 = 10
    initial_roll = print('Roll: ',die1,die2)
    initial_total = die1+die2
    print('Total: ',initial_total)
    stay_or_roll = input('(s)tay or (r)oll? ')
    next_total = initial_total
    if next_total == 21:
        print(blackjack)

    while stay_or_roll == 'r' or next_total > 21:
        next_roll = (roll_die())
        print('\nRoll: ',next_roll)
        next_total = int(next_total+ next_roll)
        print('Total: ',next_total)
        if next_total > 21:
            print('Bust!')
        dealer()
        stay_or_roll = input('(s)tay or (r)oll? ')      
            if stay_or_roll == 's':
                dealer()     

    # < Insert the rest of your code here. >

def dealer():
    ''' 
    Implements what happens on the dealer's turn. 
    Returns total which represents the dealer's
    total score.
'''

print("\n********** DEALER'S TURN **********")
die1 = random.randint(1,11)
die2 = random.randint(1,11)
if die1 == 11 and die2 == 11:
    die1 = 10
initial_roll = print('Roll: ',die1,die2)
initial_total = die1+die2
print('Total: ',initial_total)
stay_or_roll = input('Press <enter to continue ...')
next_total = initial_total
if next_total >=16 or next_total <21:
    print('done')
if next_total == 21:
    print(Blackjack)
while stay_or_roll == '' and int(next_total) <= 21:
    next_roll = (roll_die())
    print('\nRoll: ',next_roll)
    next_total = int(next_total+ next_roll)
    print('Total: ',next_total)
    if next_total > 21:
        print('Bust!')     
    stay_or_roll = input('Press <enter to continue ...')       
def main():
    ''' 
    The main driver of the program. Connects the 
    player() and dealer() functions together to
    play Blackjack Dice.
    '''

    # The user (or player) plays first.
player_total, blackjack = player()
    print(player())
    print(dealer())
    # < Insert the rest of your code here. >

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly share local variables between functions. Your practical options are to return values, set global variables, pass in a mutable object to be modified to include the data, or rewrite to use a class that keeps the values as an attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use global variables and set their values from inside the function when the function is called. This way you will be able to access the value from other functions.